# How do I split a string at the space character if not preceded by a comma

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to split text at the space character but only if the space character is not preceeded by a comma.
The following are some examples of a strings

`P3, 367 P5, 367 P5, 367`

or

`P3 P5 P5`

or

`P3, A6, A7 P4 P5` etc...

Getting them splitted at the empty space character is done as follows

```
arr = VBA.Split(ActiveCell.Value, " ")
```

The desired result is as follows:

[`P3, 367` `P5, 367` `P5, 367`]

or

[`P3` `P5` `P5`]

or

[`P3, A6, A7` `P4` `P5`] etc ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick Workaround**

Replace all `", "` with something special that does not exist in the string like `#` to escape your `", "` that you want to protect from split. So

```
P3, 367 P5, 367 P5, 367
```

turns into

```
P3#367 P5#367 P5#367
```

Then replace spaces by something else unique eg `%` so it turns into

```
P3#367%P5#367%P5#367
```

Then revert the first replace of `#` backe into its original `", "` so you get

```
P3, 367%P5, 367%P5, 367
```

And split by `%` to get

```
P3, 367
P5, 367
P5, 367
```

---

**Alternatively**

Researach how to use regular expressions in VBA: [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

Comment: I've tried using `RegEx` but your first suggestion might just be what OP needs for simplicity: `arr = Application.Substitute(Split(Replace(<string>, ", ", "%"), " "), "%", ", ")`

Comment: Thanks Peh, that did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first google result when searching for "split on a space not preceded by a comma", there's another option involving regex negative look behinds:

`(?<!,)`  (note the space after the closing `)`)

This will match on all spaces that are not preceded by a comma.

```py
import re

NO_COMMA_THEN_SPACE = r'(?<!,) '

split = re.split(
    NO_COMMA_THEN_SPACE, 
    'P3, 367 P5, 367 P5, 367'
)

assert split == ['P3, 367', 'P5, 367', 'P5, 367']
```